# Replace '{}' in Apex

Tags: json, string, replaceall

Hello everybody I am passing a Json from javascript to an Apex controller to validate some info. The problem is that the json comes with some values like this:

```
"Direction": {}
```

And I want to change them to:

```
"Direction": null
```

I trying the:

```
        wrapperWithInfo.replaceAll('{}', 'null');
```

but I am getting the next error:

```
System.StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition

public static List<String> getInformationFromLWC(String wrapperWithInfo, String recordIdPuntoSuministro){
    String newRecordIdPasoMensajeria;
    WrapperGlobal newInstance = new WrapperGlobal();
    wrapperWithInfo.replaceAll('\\{}', 'null');
    System.debug('jsonlimpio -> '+ wrapperWithInfo);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`replace(String target, String replacement)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replace) instead of [`replaceAll(String regExp, String replacement)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll):

- the first replaces each substring of a string that matches **the literal target sequence**
- the latter Replaces each substring of a string that matches **the regular expression**

Keep in mind that Strings are immutable, so you must assign the result of replace to the variable. Indeed every method that *modifies* a string (replace, substring, etc...) creates a new one.

```java
wrapperWithInfo = wrapperWithInfo.replace('{}', 'null');
```

If you want to stick with `replaceAll`, then you have to escape the curly brace as showed by TSmith

Comment: Hello I tried wht you said but it neither work

Comment: @salesforcequestions I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the curly braces as follows:

```
.replaceAll('\\{}', 'null');
```

Such braces are used to group parts of a regex together to express repetition.

Comment: Hello it did not gave me any error but it did not replace the values. I updated the question